# What's the difference between compiler and linker debug information?

Tags: delphi, debugging

I am a little confused why Delphi has Debug information in linking and debug information in compiling.

What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Debugging option in the Compiler will add the Debug information to the `DCU` files.

Debugging option in the linker will put all debug found in the `DCU` files into the exe/dll.

if you're using something like FastMM4 or memslueth you will need both options to help you find any faults.

If your releasing code you should disable the linker option to greatly reduce your exe size ( and protect your IPR ).

If you are releasing just the `DCU` files ( as a 3rd party control/library ) you should turn off the compiler setting before releasing, if you are not supplying source code.

Comment: But how does madexcept locate procedure names if i am compiling only with debugging option in the compiler ?

Comment: They're DCU's for Delphi, not OBJ's. And if you're releasing compiled code only, you might want to release two versions of the code: Compiled with and without debugging. Debugging information is not only necessary for FastMM4 and other 3rd party debuggers, it's most important for the IDE itself.

Comment: @opc0de, take a look at the `MAP` files (also a Linker option): it's the easiest way to transform Address into module and procedure name.

Comment: I've never used madexcept, but i expect youd need to enable both options, persoanlly i never disable the compiler option and just use the linker option. and Thank Cosmin for correcting my obj/dcu mistake, I need to stop using too many different compilers.

Comment: @CosminPrund thanks for your edits. So the map file gets linked into the executable so madexcept can identify procedures from memory addresses ?

Comment: No, the map file is never linked into the exe. I'm not using Madexcept so I can't guess what it's doing. If it can guess the name of procedures on a client's computer (ie: without the MAP file) then it must be using the embedded debug information. The MAP file is nice if you want to roll something of your own: it's a TEXT file and it's human readable. Almost human readable.

Comment: @Dampsquid No, madexcept works with no debugging info included at all.

Comment: I liked OBJ version better. In the fact, DCU is merely smooth and round reinvented whee... object file. Well, a proprietary alternative to it. Delphi's integrated compiler/linker/binder just keep its user safe from the knowledge of the normal toolchain. A use of the map files to build a debug information (instead of native  debugging information) is good illustration of that.

Comment: madexcept adds the map info to the exe. When you install madexcept into the IDE it automatically does this for you when you compile/build. When using the commandline compiler, you need to use a utility. IIRC it is called madexceptpath.exe and is somewhere in the madexcept installation folders.